# Composition of a weakly convergent sequence with a nonlinear function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n $ be bounded smooth domain.
Given a sequence $u_m$ in  Sobolev space $H=\left \{v\in H^2(\Omega ):\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}=0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega  \right \}$ such that $u_m$ is uniformly bounded i.e. $\|u_m\|_{H^2}\leq M$ and given the function $f(u)=u^3-u$.

If I know that $u_m\rightharpoonup u(u\in H)$ in $L^2$ sense  i.e. $\int_{\Omega}u_m v\to \int_{\Omega}u v$ for every $v\in H$. Is it true that $f(u_m)\rightharpoonup f(u)$ (in $L^2$ sense)?

Comment: The expression $u^3$ has no meaning in a general Hilbert space: we can only add vectors or multiply by a scalar.

Comment: what does it mean $u^3$?

Comment: You are right. Editted

Comment: I guess that $f(u_m)$ are also in the Sobolev space ?

Comment: What is the context of your question. It might help answering.

Comment: I try to pass to the limit after Galerkin approximation and I have non linear term. $u_m$ represent the approximating sequence.

Comment: Which is the Sobolev space ? $H_0^1$ ?

Comment: $H$  is for example $H^2$ with no flux Neuman b.c

Comment: Maybe you should write more about the context of the problem. Otherwise even if it is true, it might not be possible to prove it, without some additional structure of the problem.

Comment: Before you had written $u_m\rightharpoonup u$ in $H$, i.e weakly in $H^2$. Also you mentioned Galerkin approximations, do you use $C^1$ finite elements ?

Comment: I don't know If the base functions are smooth.

Comment: $u^3$ might be an $L^2$ function,since we can exchange some diferentiability to gain some integrability,or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I post this as answer,but I am studying myself Sobolev spaces right now, so I am not sure whether it is correct (in fact it may well be completely wrong). The argument will use embedding theorems for Sobolev spaces.

1. First we have a sequence that converges weakly in $L^2,$ but is bounded in $H^2 = W^{2,2}.$ Since $W^{2,2}$ is reflexive, the unit ball is weakly compact. So you can extract converging subsequences. But every converging subsequence converges tu $u,$ since we know that $v_m\rightharpoonup v$ in $W^{k,p}$ implies $v_m\rightharpoonup v$ in $L^p.$ A sequence in a compact (if you want also metric) space in which every converging subsequence converges to the same limit point, is itself convergent.
2. Now we know that $W^{2,2}$ embeds compactly in $L^{q},$ for $q < \frac{2n}{n - 4},$ and $n \ge 4$. For smaller $n$ we have compact embedding in $C^{k, \gamma},$ for $\gamma \in (0,1)$ and $k< 2 - n/2 - \gamma.$ Compact embeddings tell us that a weakly converging sequence in the departure space is strongly converging in the arrival space. So all in all, for $n <6,$ we know that the sequence is actually strongly converging in $L^6$.
3. Part 2 thus tells us that $u_n^3$ is in $L^2$ and this answers some of the comments. Furthermore it is strongy convergent in $L^2.$ So for $n < 6$ we have that actually $f(u_n) \rightarrow f(u)$ strongly in $L^2.$
4. Last but not least we consider the border case $n = 6.$ Here we have just continuous embedding of $W^{2,2}$ in $L^6$. So we know $u_n^3$ is in $L^2$,and we know that it has some weakly converging subsequence, since it`s norm is bounded. But is  $u_n^3\rightharpoonup u^3$? I suppose it is,but I am actually having some trouble proving it.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I consider only the case $n=3$.

You have $u_m\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2$, so it is enough to show that $u_m^3\rightharpoonup u^3$ in $L^2$. To show this we will use Sobolev compact embedding theorems, the [Bounded Convergence Theorem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319009?seq=2#page_scan_tab_contents), and the fact that if each subsequence of $y_m$ contains a strongly/weakly convergent subsequence to some $y$ then the whole sequence converges to $y$.

So, you have that $u_m\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2$ and $\|u_m\|_{H^2}\leq M$. Take an arbitrary subsequence $u_{m_k}$. Because $H^2\hookrightarrow L^\infty\Rightarrow \|u_{m_k}\|_{L^\infty}\leq cM$, where $c>0$ is the embedding constant. Further, because $u_{m_k}$ is also bounded in $H^1$, which is reflexive, it follows that there exists a further weakly convergent subsequence $u_{m_{k_l}}\rightharpoonup g\in H^1$ in $H^1\hookrightarrow L^2$ (compactly). Because the embedding is compact $u_{m_{k_l}}\to g$ in $L^2$. Now, note that $g\equiv u$, because weak limits are unique, and therefore you conclude from here that actually $u\in L^6$ since $H^1\hookrightarrow L^6$ (continuously). From the $L^2$ convergence you find a further pointwise a.e convergent subsequence, this time denote it $u_s(x)\to u(x)$ for which you still have the $L^\infty$ bound $\|u_s\|\leq cM$. Finally, you note that $u_s^3(x)\to u^3(x)$ a.e and that $\|u_s^3\|_{L^\infty}\leq c^3M^3<\infty$, and apply the Bounded Convergence Theorem to $\{u_s^3\}$ to conclude that $u_s^3\to u^3$ in $L^p,\,\forall 1\leq p<\infty$. Obviously $u_s^3\rightharpoonup u^3$ in $L^2$ also.

As a conclusion, from the very strong assumption, that $\|u_m\|_{H^2}\leq M$ and that $u_m\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2$ it follows that $u_m\to u$ in $L^p,\,\forall 1\leq p<\infty$ and also $u_m^3\to u^3$ in $L^p,\,\forall 1\leq p<\infty$.

> **Bounded Convergence Theorem:** Suppose $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is bounded,  $f,f_1,f_2,...,f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions over $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ and $M>0$ is such that
> $$\|f_n\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq M,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$$
> and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{f_n(x)}=f(x)$ a.e $x\in\Omega$. Then
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\|f_n-f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}}=0,\,\forall 1\leq p<\infty$$