# Weak convergence in different $L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Consider $p \ge \alpha \ge 1.$

If a sequence converges weakly in $L^p,$ say $u_n \rightharpoonup u$, is it true that: $$u_n^{\alpha} \rightharpoonup u^{\alpha} \text{ in $L^{p/ \alpha}$}$$

This question came to me, while trying to solve the following:

[Composition of a weakly convergent sequence with a nonlinear function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685967/composition-of-a-weakly-convergent-sequence-with-a-nonlinear-function/1688244#1688244)

We can always argue that $u_n^{\alpha}$ has a converging subsequence, but I couldn't go anywhere with this.

Comment: If we strengthen the conditions as in the linked question, you get it. See my answer there: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1691807/254733

Comment: @Svetoslav I am sorry, but I don't really understand. In your reply you don't strengthen the hypothesis. You are considering the special case $ n=3$. The argument you use (compact embeddings) can be extended up to $ n=5$, as I state in my answer. But what if $n=6$? Here we do not have compact embeddings, so I came up with this question.

Comment: In my answer, the dimension actually doesn't matter, because I do not use that $H^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^{p*}$ for $p^*<6$. I just mention it. What is actually used is that $H^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^2$, so that we get a convergent subsequence in $L^2$ and a.e convergent subsequence.

Comment: For your question here, I do not think that you can get anything better than a convergent subsequence $u_{n_k}^\alpha\rightharpoonup u^\alpha$.

Comment: Even in my answer to the linked question, you can use that $H^2$ is compactly embedded in $H^1$ so you can get a convergent subsequence in $H^1$. Simply the condition for uniform boundedness of the $H^2$- norms is very strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $p=\alpha=2$ and that we work on the unit interval. If the sequence $\left(u_n^2\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges weakly to $u^2$ in $\mathbb L^1$, then using the fact that the constant function equal to $1$ belongs to $\left(\mathbb L^1\right)'$, we derive that $$\tag{*}\lVert u_n\rVert_2\to \lVert u\rVert_2.$$ If $\left(u_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges to $u$ weakly in $\mathbb L^2$, then we can derive with the help of (*) that $\lVert u_n-u\rVert_2$ strongly in $\mathbb L^2$.

Therefore, any sequence in $\mathbb L^2(0,1)$ with converges in $\mathbb L^2$ weakly but not strongly qualifies for a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

Since $u_n\in L^p$ it holds $u_n^\alpha\in L^\frac{p}{\alpha}$. That should be correct so far. For $p\not=\alpha$ your Claim holds since $L^q$ ist reflexiv for $1<q<\infty$. If $p=\alpha$ I have no Idea sorry. ;)

Comment: It´s already something :) How do you use reflexivity?

Comment: in reflexive Spaces every bounded sequence has a converging subsequence. Your sequence is bounded since u_n converges. Then use uniqueness of limits and I think that should solve your problem. But I'm not 100% sure ;)

Comment: Yes,that´s what I thought to do (and it´s good you point out that it doesn´t work for $\alpha =p$). But also if I knew $u_n^\alpha$ would converge, I wouldn´t know how to prove that the limit is $u$.

Comment: The limit of $u_n^\alpha$ is $u^\alpha$ since $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ and the limit is unique. I hope I understood your question ^^

Comment: You could start from Theorem 2 here: www.scielo.br/pdf/aabc/v75n1/v75n1a02.pdf

Comment: @Siminore thanks for the reference. But it doesn´t keep things very simple. Anyhow, can I always extract an almoast sure converging subsequence from a weakly converging sequence? Because in the paper it seems to me that they treat (in great generality) the a.s. and weak continuity of Nemytskii operators.