# Strong $L^p$ convergence and weak $H^{1,p}$ convergence

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Provided for a sequence $u_n$ we know

\begin{eqnarray}
u_n \rightarrow u \ \ \ \text{strongly in } L^p(\Omega) \\
u_n \rightharpoonup u \ \ \ \text{weakly in } H^{1,p}(\Omega),
\end{eqnarray}

Can we conclude something like

\begin{equation}
|\nabla u_n|^q \rightharpoonup |\nabla u|^q \ \ \ \text{weakly in } L^{\frac{p}{q}}(\Omega)
\end{equation}

for $q<p$? We obviously have weak convergence of $|\nabla u_n|^q$ to at least some unidentified limit and the strong $L^p$-convergence implies

\begin{equation}
u_n^q \rightarrow u^q \ \ \ \text{in } L^{\frac{p}{q}}(\Omega)
\end{equation}

but as far as I see this only gives us

\begin{equation}
\nabla u_n^q \rightharpoonup \nabla u^q \ \ \ \text{in } L^{\frac{p}{q}}(\Omega).
\end{equation}

Is what I am trying to show wrong?

Comment: I don't think that it is correct, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688264/weak-convergence-in-different-lp-spaces).

Comment: Yes, you are probably right, thank you.